# Loading External data (in Excel/CSV) to blockchain engine

Tags: solidity, json-rpc, database, external-api

I am new to solidity blockchain. I have transaction dataset in csv files. I want to load it automatically to blockchain using ethereum solidity.
How can I do it? Is there any UI available? Any guide would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

it is better to use JSON files to make your life easier since ethereum only deals with JSON files using RPC calls. if you can put your data in JSON files then I can show you how it it done.
Think about designing an API : https://blockchain.info/de/api/blockchain_api

Comment: I can convert my data to json. Let me do it and send it to you.

Comment: The aim is to design an UI where I can dump data automatically to blockchain engine.